# Database abstraction layer for AIR? (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

Just check with you folks to see if there is any library or framework that provides a database abstraction layer in ActionScript3 for an AIR application to access a local SQLite database.

Comment: There's not that much to abstract, is there? I believe [Christophe Coenraets](http://coenraets.org/blog/) was working on an ORM for AIR/SQLite, but I don't think the project was ever finished.

Comment: An ORM would be great, I was hoping at least there is something like Spring's JdbcTemplate. But that's ok, I can write my own data access layer. Just want to do a quick check before I "reinvent" the wheel.

Comment: Not directly answering (but maybe useful some way): http://code.google.com/p/dao-ext/

Comment: I've just uploaded my library (I use it for my app PageOne Curator, http://pageonecurator.com). See it at https://github.com/pranavh/AS3SQLite/

I've not yet written docs, a basic code example is in progress

Comment: @PranavHosangadi - Thanks for sharing the project. That's a great start. Can you post this in the Answer section so that I can mark it as a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [AS3-SPOD](https://github.com/stickupkid/as3-spod), we use it on a daily basis on a rather high profile project, no problems so far.

Comment: This one sure looks interesting: I'm definitely gonna try it out if the occasion presents itself.

Answer (score 1):

My own two cents: https://github.com/pranavh/AS3SQLite/

Use it, extend it, share it, I'm happy if it helps you. Do contribute back to the project if you extend it, though.

Comment: [Moved - Unnecessarily deleted]

@Pranav - I just checked it out, and while (just my own opinion here) most SQLStatements would make sense to me as just a single text property - since usually the creates, drops, selects, etc are completely custom to the db at hand being built with the project, I do commend you on the idea of building a statement queue - since this can greatly simplify most Responders where a lot of code is boiler plate sequencing when using asynch calls.

Comment: [Hey Moderator: lift the comment size restriction - this is just dumb]

I would make one suggestion aka food for thought - in cases with insert/update - a lot of times the data fetched will now need a reference as a FK to some other insert/update statement, and before commit can be called - the 'next' sqlstatement needs the result of the first.

Great job though on just simplifying this part.